# How to implement engine class which doesn't block its user

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, asynchronous

I have class, lets call it "Engine", which contains something like event loop, logic of which can be explained by the following pseudo code:

```
for(;;) {
  int interruptId;
  waitForInterrupt(); // blocking wait
  switch(interruptId) {
    case REQUEST_DATA:
    doSomeStuff();

    ...
  }
}
```

the event loop is intended for interrupts processing (which come from driver of a hardware device).
Engine will be used by client. Client should be able to start/stop engine.
But starting the engine shouldn't suspend the client.

My intention: when Engine is started it starts a new thread where event loop for(;;) is executed.

Question is it a solution to go, could you propose existing design patterns applicable in this case, any advices on implementations and possible bottlenecks that I should take into account.

NB!!!Update: Engine class is provided to a client as a dynamic library

Comment: if your client already has an event loop, you could merge the engine event loop into it if you want to avoid the extra thread.

Comment: Engine class is provided to a client as a separate dynamic library, so I can't merge their loops

Comment: "merge" was probably a bad choice of words - how about "call from" - ie. for every client event loop iteration, you also check if the engine has a pending event (if so, you process the engine event - if not, you just do the next client loop iteration).

Comment: This will not work, as Engine loop contains blocking call hence client will be also blocked till the next interrupt from a driver, which isn't a kind of behavior I want

Comment: if the engine library doesn't provide any functionality that would allow you to combine both event loops into one, you're kind of forced to have two threads (one for each event loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

struct MsgFromAgent {
  std::string str;
};

struct MsgToAgent {
  std::string str;
};

struct IClient {
  virtual void onMsgFromBC(MsgFromAgent& msg) = 0;
  virtual void onTimeout() = 0;
  virtual ~IClient() {};
};

struct Engine {
  Engine(IClient& client) : isRunning(false), client(client) { }
  ~Engine() {
    // we expect that if client started the engine
    // client must stop it before Engine will be destructed
    assert(!isRunning && "Running engine should be stoped by the client");

    // in any way, handle exceptional situation if it arises
    if(isRunning) {
      isRunning = false;
      th.join();
    }
  }
  void start() {
    isRunning = true;
    th = std::thread(std::bind(&Engine::eventLoop, this));
  }
  bool write(const MsgToAgent& msg) {
    // some code
  }
  void stop() {
    isRunning = false;
    th.join();
  }
  void eventLoop() {
    while(isRunning) {
      // blocking calls, that return control when certain interrupts from hardware arrives

      // if interrupt haven't arraived within certain time limit:
      try {
        client.onTimeout();
      } catch(...) {

      }

      // interrupt about incomming msg:
      MsgFromAgent dummyMsg;
      try {
        client.onMsgFromBC(dummyMsg);
      }
      catch (...) {

      }
    }
  }
  bool isRunning;
  std::thread th;
  IClient& client;
};

struct Client : public IClient {
  Client() : e(*this)  {

  };
  ~Client() {
  }
  void onMsgFromBC(MsgFromAgent& msg) {
    std::cout << "On message\n";
  }
  void onTimeout() {
    std::cout << "On timeout\n";
  }
  Engine e;
};

int main() {
  Client c;
  return 0;
}
```